# Grouping array elements of same value in each line while printing - Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, string-length

there is a way to print elements of a String array sorted for word length at every line?
So, considering the code below,

```
String[] arr = {"a", "b", "cc", "dd", "ee", "fff", "hhh"};
            
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```

there is a way to change the output from:

"a b cc dd ee fff hhh"

to

"a b

cc dd ee

fff hhh"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Remember that StackOverflow is not a website for homework assignments and this looks like one. Please describe the steps you tried and where exactly are you having trouble, thanks.

Comment: 1. The elements are NOT of the _same value_, they have the same length  2. The elements are currently sorted by length.  Is the input array always sorted this way?  How should the output look when the elements are mixed?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `stream` for that job:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, 
                    Collectors.joining(" ")))
      .values().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
a b
cc dd ee
fff hhh
```

Comment: I believe that for a person which does not know how to group strings of the same length, streams are do complex to understand.
But great code nonetheless.

Comment: I agree, IMO you should feel comfortable with `loops` before getting into `streams`

Comment: Thanks a lot to Oboe ant to eveyone helped. Actually I’m a beginner (as you probably fully understood from my post) and I tought it would be possible to solve the problem using classic for loop.

I already started to try to understand how stream works so, first of all, thank’you for giving me the opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Before spoilering the answer, I will give you some hints:

1. Create a variable that stores the length of the previous string. (Set to Integer.MAX_Value for beginning)
2. Iterate through the array. If the previousLength is smaller than the length of the currentString, insert a newline.
3. Print the current string with a whitespace at the end.
4. Set the variable in 1 to the length of the current string
5. End of the loop

Please try to code this yourself, as this helps you to better understand Java.

Comment: You don't need a temporary variable. Just check whether current length and previous length is different to print new line. In all cases, you always print the value.
One problem is first item will cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, so you have two ways to solve it:
1. if (index > 0 and current length and previous length is different) then print new line.
2. Print first item first, then loop start with index = 1

Comment: You should always try to use a forEach loop. That thing makes your life easier. You don't need to check for an index and can safely iterate through the array. In that case you need a single integer (4 byte length). I think the 4 byte more memory don't make a big difference in your application speed, but make your application more robust.

Comment: To be honest, I love Java 8, 11 and any further version but I don't want to use a strange syntax to who don't know much about newer Java version. And I think use a non-(effectively) final variable inside a forEach is impossible.

Comment: Here is mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69608205/16821720

Answer (score -1):

So here is my take on this problem. It doesn't involve using indices and avoids streams as this is not something a beginner should start with.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"a", "b", "cc", "dd", "ee", "fff", "hhh"};
        int previousLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
        for (String currentString: arr){
            if(previousLength < currentString.length()){
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.print(currentString+" ");
            previousLength = currentString.length();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't work as it assumes ```arr``` is already sorted by length to begin with.

Comment: Hi @SamTV, thanks a lot for your contribution to my problem that, as a beginner, it’s a little easyer to understand.

I have a question: can you explain me the specific reason why you chose to set value of previousLength to Integer.MAX_VALUE ?

I’m asking because i tryed to set it to 0 and code seems to work properly anyway.

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hi @gianni85 I am glad that I could help you. I used Integer.MaxValue that in no circumstance a newline will be printed at the beginning (previousLength<currenStrint.length) will be immediately true if you initialize previousLength with 0.

Comment: Nik Vinter please read the assignement carefully. It is just about formatting the input correctly. Sorting the array is not necessary.

Comment: @SamTV "print elements of a String array sorted for word length at every line" assumes that given any String array the output should be its contents sorted by word length